# Automatic Git Commit like `golang` repo in Github?

Tags: git, mercurial, hook

https://github.com/jnwhiteh/golang

This mirrors exactly the same things from `hg` source Go code. What if I want to do the similar thing? How do I mirror `mecurial` repository in GitHub and automate the commit commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use something like [git-remote-hg](https://github.com/felipec/git-remote-hg) to pull from mercurial directly.

If it's your mercurial repo then you can setup a commit [hook](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook) that would push the changes to your git repo, otherwise you have to poll for a change log every few minutes (or using cron) and then push the changes if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **Hg-Git mercurial plugin**, which was originally developed by the folks at GitHub (so says its home page :), and is currently maintained by Augie Fackler.

See an example of usage to push to github in its home page: http://hg-git.github.io/